# Multiple bits gates

Tags: verilog

I'd like to know how I could go about using AND, OR and other gates for multiple bits inputs. I was trying to build a 2:1 MUX but I got this error:

`Expression width 2 does not match width 1 of logic gate array port 1.`

Here's the code

```
module mux_21 #(parameter width = 1) (
    input [width-1:0] d0, d1,
    input s,
    output [width-1:0] y
);
    wire [width-1:0] ns, y1, y2;
    not  g1 (ns, s);
    and  g2 (y1, d0, ns);
    and  g3 (y2, d1, s);
    or   g4 (y, y1, y2);
endmodule
```

Comment: The basic logic gates have single-bit inputs and outputs. You need a number of `width` gates of each. Or you just use bitwise operators instead of instantiating the logic gates by hand.

Comment: why do you use gates at all?

Comment: because I was asked to use structural design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive gates are always single bit. You need to create instance for each bit combination.

The most common way to is with a generate for-loop. Generate logic goes through static unrolled during the elaboration phase of compile.

```
genvar gidx;
wire ns;
wire [width-1:0] y1, y2;
not  g1 (ns, s);
generate
  for(gidx=0; gidx<width; gidx=gidx+1) begin : mux
    and  g2 (y1[gidx], d0[gidx], ns );
    and  g3 (y2[gidx], d1[gidx], s );
    or   g4 (y[gidx], y1[gidx], y2[gidx] );
  end
endgenerate
```

You could also create a range of instances. This is a feature that has existed longer then the generate construct but less commonly used and I notices some synthesizers don't support it (ex Yosys 0.9 on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/)).

```
wire ns;
wire [width-1:0] y1, y2;
not  g1 (ns, s);
and  g2 [width-1:0] (y1, d0, ns);
and  g3 [width-1:0] (y2, d1, s);
or   g4 [width-1:0] (y, y1, y2);
```